# Add another Div tag to the same row

Tags: html, css, width, division

I am trying to add another div  but it always displayed as the second row..All I need all to be all the same row and align to each other.

html code

```
        <div class="content-grids">
                    <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="content-grid">

                      <div class="content-grid-info">
                        <h3>All inclusive Packages</h3>
                        <p>Airfares + Accomodation(ocean View) + 3 Meals daily + House Beverages + Activities(incl Kids Club)                           </p>



                      <div class="content-grid-info">
                        <h3>4 nights $1,299</h3>
                         </div>



                        <div class="content-grid-info">
                            <h3>7 nights $1,189</h3>
                        </div>


                </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-grids{
 padding: 3.5em 0 3.7em 0;
margin:0 0 40px 0px;
}
.content-grid-info p{
    font-size: 0.875em;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;

.content-grid-info h3{
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 400;
```

Been doing some updates and changes to the style sheet still same issues

Comment: are you trying to add `.content-grid` as other div?

Comment: @Gaurav have edits the CSS..

Comment: which div you want to add in row? If its `.content-grid` then answer is already given..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with your html code there were some div missing to close

Below is the fixed code its working fine

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-grids">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="content-grid">
            <div class="content-grid-info">
                <h3>All inclusive Packages</h3>
                <p>Airfares + Accomodation(ocean View) + 3 Meals daily + House Beverages + Activities(incl Kids Club)                           </p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-grid-info">
                <h3>4 nights $1,299</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="content-grid-info">
                <h3>7 nights $1,189</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-grid">
            <div class="content-grid-info">
                <h3>All inclusive Packages</h3>
                <p>Airfares + Accomodation(ocean View) + 3 Meals daily + House Beverages + Activities(incl Kids Club)                           </p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-grid-info">
                <h3>4 nights $1,299</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="content-grid-info">
                <h3>7 nights $1,189</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/yvpfxg8h/

Comment: i can see its 3 rows..how to add all in the same row eg a, b, c, d,

Comment: u have used `width:33.33%` use `width:25%` then 4 in a row will come

Answer (score 0):

Check this code sample:

```
  <div class="content-grids">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="content-grid float-left">
            <h3 class="content-grid-info float-left">All inclusive Packages</h3>
            <p class="float-left">Airfares + Accomodation(ocean View) + 3 Meals daily + House Beverages + Activities(incl Kids Club) </p>

            <div class="content-grid-info float-left">
                <h3 class="float-left">4 nights $1,299</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="content-grid-info float-left">
                <h3 class="float-left">7 nights $1,189</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyrraw

Comment: how can you change someone's html structure